# Selenium: execute script after Google Tag Manager has loaded

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-tag-manager

I'm loading a URL in selenium, which uses Google Tag Manager to inject a script.

```
<script src="http://sample.com/file.js" />
```

I'm loading the URL in the webdriver using this

```
await driver.get('https://sample-page-that-uses-gtm.com)
```

When I go to that URL in my browser (not selenium driver), and manually check the script in the elements tab and console (query selector), I can successfully find the script. However, this is not the case in Selenium. I manually opened console of the Selenium Webdriver and ran a check for the presence of the injected script, but there was none detected.

This is what I ran on the console

```
document.querySelector('script[src="http://sample.com/file.js"]')
```

It finds the script on the browser, but not on Webdriver. Is this a problem with using GTM on Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

try to use an expected condition to force the code to wait before checking if the script is present:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//script[@src='http://sample.com/file.js']")))
```

this might be happening because you're checking for the script before it gets loaded in the DOM, if this does not solve your problem, please update your question with an example of a URL that uses Google Tag Manager  and doesn't load on selenium, as this will help identify the problem